# Is it possible for an airliner to safely fly with doors open?

Tags: aerodynamics, airliner

From another [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/can-a-commercial-airliner-be-used-for-military-purposes) asks about the possibility of dropping bombs from converted airliners. My question: is it possible to safely fly aircraft with a door open for the whole flight envelope? Would the aerodynamics be affected if we did not close the door?

I am not asking about the need of oxygen for the crew, just about the aerodynamics involved. I know the plane would not be pressurized.

Comment: vasin, I changed the title to specify "an airliner," since that's what your question body and tags say. In this question, the answers differ quite a bit between those cases (it's completely a non-incident to open the door of the PA-28 I fly in flight, for example, and my instructor did so multiple times.) If you're interested in non-airliners, too, feel free to edit it back or ask another question.

Comment: It will add some drag, for sure, but C-130's regularly fly with their back doors open which you see in any movie where material or parachuters are jumping out the back.  https://chivethebrigade.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/c-130-back-door-920-81.jpg

Comment: Flying with the rear door open isn't limited to military airlifters -- Skydive Perris has a DC-9-21 that had its rear airstairs removed and uses it for skydiving operations, taking folks up to 13,000' for a real D.B. Cooper experience.

Answer (score 50):

The [Stratospheric Observatory for Infrared Astronomy (SOFIA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratospheric_Observatory_for_Infrared_Astronomy) is a modified 747 that has an 5.5 m x 4.1 m door that is opened during flight for the installed in infrared telescope. But the door is usually closed during takeoff and landing.

But according to this [story](http://spacenews.com/successful-landing-stuck-door-advances-sofia-testing/) there are emergency procedures to land with an open door and it had to do so once, when it became stuck half open.

[image]
[image]
Images courtesy Wikipedia

Comment: Is the door closed at takeoff and landing out of aerodynamic concerns, or just to protect the equipment from bird strikes and foreign objects on the runway?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: There are other concerns as well for closing the door. For instance, IR telescopes must run very cool, so closing the door allows the team to cool the telescope cooler than ambient before take off, and additionally to flood the "trunk" with nitrogen to prevent condensation when returning to a higher-temperature environment on landing.

Comment: This seems to me the only "correct" answer, as it's the only one assuming a modern airliner opening *a door* in a way that the engineers considered "safe". Having *survived* structural damage (which other answers point at) doesn't equal "safe operation" the way I understood the question. Nice find!

Comment: @DevSolar I'd assume that this section of this aircraft is not within the pressure vessel, though (since the crew probably wants to breathe while it's open,) so it's quite different from opening a door in flight in a normal airliner.

Comment: @DevSolar I modified my answer to mention an actual (non-modified) airliner that did fly with a door open without any structural damage involved.

Comment: @reirab: [You are correct.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratospheric_Observatory_for_Infrared_Astronomy#The_SOFIA_aircraft)  Quoth Wikipedia: "The telescope is mounted in the aft end of the fuselage behind a pressurized bulkhead. The telescope's focal point is located at a science instruments suite in the pressurized, center section of the fuselage, requiring part of the telescope to pass through the pressure bulkhead."

Answer (score 46):

Aloha Airlines [Flight 243](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243) proved that it's possible for a plane to fly with about 25% of its roof missing. The door, however, appears to have remained closed until landing.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243_fuselage.png]<sup>Image courtesy Wikipedia</sup>

Comment: This does indeed imply that a door missing might also be survivable.

Comment: The question specifies fly **safely**. Aloha 243 was not safe: it resulted in one death and injuries to about two-thirds of the passengers. Having said that, it's unclear how many of the injuries were as an immediate result of the roof coming off and how many were sustained by flying around in a plane with no roof.

Comment: Valid point, @DavidRicherby, however if one considers _safe_ to be _survivable_ then this seems to be a reasonable example. (After all, don't pilots consider `any landing that you can walk away from is a good one`?) _Not trying to minimize the death or injuries, just making a point about an extreme example of the OPs question_

Comment: Virtually no one considers "survivable" to be "safe".

Comment: @FreeMan Of course I don't consider "safe" to mean "survivable"! That would be a ludicrous definition of "safe". If somebody says to you, "Have a safe flight!" do you think they mean "Have a flight where the roof blows off the aircraft, one of the flight attendants falls 24,000ft into the ocean, eight other people are seriously injured, almost everyone else receives minor injuries and the plane is written off?" I don't. I guess I expect more of an airline than you do.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the aircraft flew safely. The fatality happened due to the roof breaking open during flight in an uncontrolled manner, not due to there being no roof.

Comment: Answer does not answer the question, door is intact during the flight.

Comment: @jwenting: The aircraft *flew*, full stop. I very much doubt that there was anything "safe" about it, structurally or aerodynamically. (They wouldn't take off in it again, now would they?) I don't think that "not crashed" equals "safe".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry but you reminded me of this... http://youtu.be/WcU4t6zRAKg

Comment: @DevSolar safely as in "no further fatalities and injuries" and it didn't crash. Of course the incident left it structurally unsound, but that wasn't so much the result of flying with a hole in the roof as much as the roof tearing away in the first place.

Comment: @jwenting: It was structurally unsound to begin with, due to extensive fatigue damage.  As were three of Aloha's other 737s, two of which were scrapped and one repaired.

Comment: @Sean of course, but that soundness got even worse with the roof gone, as parts of the aircraft that had not been damaged by fatigue got exposed to severe stresses.

Comment: @jwenting: ...there were parts of that aircraft's fuselage that _hadn't_ already been severely damaged by fatigue?

Answer (score 28):

[Check out my answer here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/open-door-on-small-plane/15397#15397) to a similar question (about what would happen if you opened a door in flight). In short it depends largely on the plane but in the most general way of looking at it. You could do it up until you would need to pressurize the plane (or you would have to wear $\rm O_2$ masks or something to be able to breathe).

[UA Flight 811](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_811) was able to make a safe descent and return to the airport after its door blew out, so large planes are maneuverable without a door.

[image]

Planes like the [DC-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-3) used in WWII for paratrooping regularly ran with their doors open.

[image]

If you consider rear cargo ramps doors, the [C-130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-130_Hercules) can open its rear ramp for [HALO jumping](http://specialoperations.com/29014/worlds-first-combat-h-l-o-jump/) at [high altitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_military_parachuting).

> In typical HALO/HAHO insertions the troops jump from altitudes between 15,000 feet (4,600 m) and 35,000 feet (11,000 m)

[image]

There is at least one other powered glider I can think of that can open its doors mid-flight...

[image]

Comment: The DC-3 example should pretty much answer this question in the affirmative.

Comment: Agreed however there are other cases involving pressurized planes mentioned here that should not be over looked.

Comment: Your last picture (Spaceshuttle) may very well be taken outside the atmosphere. In my opinion, it has nothing to do with the question unless you provide an example of a Spaceshuttle opening it's doors during atmospheric flight.

Comment: @Mast - I think that last picture was meant with tongue firmly in cheek. I thought it was funny, at least.

Comment: @Mast, Floris is correct it was meant to add some humor, the rest of my answer is on topic and through enough.

Comment: The answer is definitely on-topic afar from that. Especially the C130 is a good thought. It's easy to miss paratrooper planes often have their doors open for longer periods of time.

Comment: Well, the question was actually tagged "airliner" even before I edited that into the title, so I don't think the C-130 really counts there, though it is a good point nonetheless. The question would be very broad if it included any airplane, since the consequences of opening the door on a pressurized or an unpressurized aircraft are quite different. Also, I'm not quite sure that the last picture there really counts as 'flight.' ;-)

Comment: There is a whole section of the FAR that covers space flight and it is very much considered flight. You actually need up through your instrument rating to fly the shuttle. http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=2abf0c470116714c2fe8c9e875ece5c0&mc=true&node=pt14.4.460&rgn=div5#se14.4.460_15

Comment: @Dave, interesting that it doesn't seem to require a multi-engine rating.

Comment: @Dave It looks like the FARs are more concerned with the atmospheric portion of the operations (launch and reentry,) which much more legitimately count as flight. Operations actually in space seem much more questionable to consider 'flight,' given the lack of an atmosphere in which to fly.

Comment: @FreeMan Well, the FARs are for spaceflight in general, not just the shuttle. There are single-engine rockets. :)

Answer (score 18):

Since comments mentioned that not all of the outcomes from [Aloha 243](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloha_Airlines_Flight_243) were exactly safe, here's another example that actually was quite safe:

[image: Southwest 812]

[Southwest 812](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwest_Airlines_Flight_812) had a large hole open in the roof during flight at cruise altitude, resulting in rapid depressurization at 34,000 ft. 2 of the 123 people on board (a flight attendant and a passenger) suffered minor injuries. The plane diverted to Yuma, Arizona and landed safely about 26 minutes after the depressurization. As with the other cases, the doors were technically shut, but I'm not so sure that that made much difference.

Furthermore, this was *not the first time this had happened.* Less than 2 years before this incident, [Southwest 2294](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwest_Airlines_Flight_2294) had a similar incident (though with a smaller hole) and safely diverted to Charleston, WV with *no injuries at all.*

What's more: according to the [FAA's registry](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=N387SW) and [airfleets.net](http://www.airfleets.net/ficheapp/plane-b737-26602.htm), it looks like both of these aircraft were returned to service and are still actively flying for Southwest! So, it looks like both the "you can walk away from it" requirement and the "the aircraft is reusable" preference were met in both instances.

---

### The Boeing 727

Another case that actually doesn't involve any structural damage at all is the 727 and its airstair. In the famous case of [D.B. Cooper's hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._B._Cooper#Back_in_the_air), this occurred while the aircraft was pressurized. According to the wiki on the incident, the result was the following:

> The crew soon noticed a subjective change of air pressure, indicating that the aft door was open.
>
> At approximately 8:13 pm the aircraft's tail section sustained a sudden upward movement, significant enough to require trimming to bring the plane back to level flight.[33] At approximately 10:15 pm Scott and Rataczak landed the 727, with the aft airstair still deployed, at Reno Airport.

Additionally, some skydiving clubs even offered dives from the 727 for many years, though these presumably didn't pressurize the cabin. I'm not sure whether this is still offered.

Comment: Well done! I just went with the one I knew of.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Convair 880 with cargo door open.]

Yes they can, here's a Convair 880 with cargo door open.

[image: DC-8 with Door open]

DC-8 with cargo door open.

Comment: Was this from a flight-test, perhaps?

Comment: According to this it was at MIA in 1979. http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/read.main/866590/ and the DC-8 is also at MIA in 1989  http://www.airliners.net/photo/203157/L/

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject they were the result of the door not being properly latched and coming open during flight.

Comment: @jwenting -- oops!

Comment: @SportsRacer: Must be the salt air corroding the latches...

Answer (score 10):

For the *whole* flight envelope, maybe not. Depends on the door design. Gear doors frequently have speed limits before they fly off on their own. Large openings create substantial drag, so we may find that the envelope is self-limiting: the aircraft can no longer reach speeds and/or altitudes where the opening is a big problem.

There are too many variables for a simple answer.

Comment: gear doors have speed limits because they extend into the airflow during flight. The cabin doors would rotate inward, keeping them out of the high speed air flowing past the outside. It would probably get rather noisy... A greater concern I have is maintaining structural integrity for long periods on an aircraft that has a cabin designed to be used while pressurised. This would mean the aircraft can only operate at low pressure altitude with the door open.

Comment: @jwenting Why would being unpressurized affect the structural integrity of the aircraft? Wouldn't the aircraft actually experience much less stress in the case of being unpressurized (until it crashed due to unconscious pilots, at least?) There have been quite a few instances of pressurized aircraft becoming depressurized and continuing at cruise flight levels (due to incapacitated pilots) and I don't recall any structural problems in any of them, prior to the aircraft running out of fuel and flying into terrain. The occupants may experience lots of stress, but the airframe shouldn't.

Comment: @reirab It's not the lack of pressurisation I'm concerned with, it's the dynamic stresses on things like the door frames from the turbulent airflow that would result from the doors being open during flight. They're not designed to handle those stresses in most aircraft.

Comment: @jwenting: Or, potentially, [the dynamic stresses from the process of depressurisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Airlines_Flight_981).

Answer (score 1):

Biplanes and ultra-lights don't have any doors at all. In general, for any plane the wing, the empennage and, to a lesser extent, the surface area on the lower part of the fuselage is all that is important. If you installed structure-reinforcing crossbars you could remove the entire fuselage wall of a commercial jet and it would still fly.

Comment: [Citation needed]. A reinforced airliner with the fuselage wall removed would have a lot of drag. And how much of the fuselage wall is needed for strength? (Admittedly, I assume there'll be no cargo or passengers so you could afford to weaken the structure somewhat.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Note that I specifically said "structure-reinforcing crossbars" would be needed. He just asked if it would fly, not if it would fly well.

Comment: Also note that the question specified "airliner". Not too many ultra-light airliners that I'm aware of, though I may be wrong.

Comment: 3 seats is the most I can find in anything that qualifies as an ultralight.